# Mapping a string into a list of pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

I have a for loop that iterates through a string and returns pairs of each character and the next following one:

```
>>> word = 'abcdef'
>>> for i in range(len(word)-1):
...     print word[i:i+2]
...
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
```

Is it possible to write this using a map/filter combination instead? I'm having a problem figuring out how to get the next character instead of using `i+2`.

I've tried to pass the word twice to map them together like this:

```
>>> word = 'abcdef'
>>> map(lambda x, y: x+y, word, word[1:])
```

But I'm unsure how to avoid the concatenation error with a str and None:

```
>>> map(lambda x, y: x+y, word, word[1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: @GiladGreen It only works in Py3, not in Py2

Comment: @schwobaseggl - oh :) good to know :) relatively new to python

Comment: @schwobaseggl I added the `python-3.x` tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` *word* and *word[1:]* and then use map to join adjacent letters:

```
>>> word = 'abcdef'
>>> map(lambda x: ''.join(x), zip(word, word[1:]))    
# zip function goes as far as the shortest argument, so there is no need to remove the last 
# element from word here             

# ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```

---

The extra `lambda` can be removed with just the join function as commented by @Chepner:

```
>>> map(''.join, zip(word, word[1:]))

# ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```

---

You can also use list-comprehension with the `zip` function:

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(word, word[1:])]

# ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```

Comment: No need for the `lambda`; `''.join` is sufficient.

Comment: @chepner Hmm. right. Just can't help to add extra lambdas. :) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I rather like this solution because of the use of zip. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This solves your problem:

```
list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, word[:-1], word[1:]))
```

Just ignoring the last element of word for the first iterable (word[:-1])

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution because it is memory efficient and does not have to duplicate list to combine them.

```
def last_and_current(iterator):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    last = next(iterator)
    for current in iterator:
        yield last, current
        last = current

print [l + c for l, c in last_and_current('abcdef')]
```